# Trouble connecting db4free.net database to EF core using UseMySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

I am having a lot of trouble connecting my db4free.net database to EF core, I have a Local and a Cloud DB context, both inheriting from IDatabase.

CloudDatabase.cs:

```cs
namespace <MyActualProjectName>.DatabaseCore
{
    public class CloudDatabase : DbContext, IDatabase
    {

        public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }

        private string? DbPath;
        private IConfiguration config;

        public CloudDatabase(IConfiguration configuration) {
            config = configuration;
            DbPath = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(DbPath!);
        }
    }
}
```

I generated the migration using `dotnet ef` cli, and that worked.

I tried running the migration using `dotnet ef database update --context <MyProjectName>.DatabaseCore.CloudDatabase` but I get this error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Applying migration '20230830041438_CreateUserTable'.
Failed executing DbCommand (126ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `<MyActualDatabaseName>`
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user '<MyActualUsername>'@'%' to database '<MyActualDatabaseName>'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacketAsync(Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResultAsync(Int32 affectedRow, Int64 insertedId, Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResultAsync(Int32 statementId, Int32 affectedRows, Int64 insertedId, Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResultAsync(Int32 statementId, Boolean force, Boolean execAsync)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResultAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResultAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
Access denied for user '<MyActualUsername>'@'%' to database '<MyActualDatabaseName>'
```

The weird part is that it created this table [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Tf8.png) successfully...

But it cant seem to create the users table.

My connection string looks like this:

```cs
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=db4free.net;port=3306;database=<DatabaseName>;user=<username>;password=<password>"
}
```

I have tried changing my connection string format, adding http:// and https:// to the server value. I made absolutely certain that it is using the correct password. (it has to be correct, otherwise it would not have been able to create the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table.)

I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Well, something is not roght with your user name or password or acceas rights to that database.

Comment: yeah its something weird on db4free.net's database. I ended up swapping to AWS RDS and it works just fine :)